# Codeigniter w. Smarty - set_value() implention

Tags: codeigniter, smarty

I have implented [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/) in my project, and i need a good workaround to use the function [set_value()](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html#repopulatingform) to repopulate forms.

I could set the values manually by passing the values in my controller.
But thats seems like a hotfix, and I'm looking for something dynamicly.

Any ideas?

Comment: Register it as a smarty function. http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/api.register.plugin.tpl

Comment: Thank you. That works as intented! Perfect.
You should make an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Register it as a smarty function. smarty.net/docs/en/api.register.plugin.tpl
- #sofl