# Codeigniter Smarty set_value

Tags: forms, codeigniter, smarty, setvalue

Somehow I barely manage to use Smarty with Codeigniter. Before, I used it in view PHP code to set a value when I received a form validation print error. I did it this way:

```
value="<?php echo set_value('termin'); ?>"
```

How to do that in Smarty?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Codeigniter w. Smarty - set\_value() implention](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23275023/codeigniter-w-smarty-set-value-implention)

Comment: That answer didn't help me